# Doing assertions inside callback of mocked readline module with jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to test a few things inside a callback that deals with user input. I'm using the [readline](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/readline.html) module from `nodejs` in Jest (similar to [the example](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/readline.html#readline_readline) given in the docs). I can't figure out how I can do assertions inside that callback.

For example: within the callback of `readline.createInterface().question()` I'm calling `writeFileSync`. I want to test *how* or *if* `writeFileSync` (or any other function in the callback) is called.

```
// file.js
const { writeFileSync } = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const copyFile = () => {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });

    rl.question('What is the file name?', (userInput) => {
        /**
         * I want to some assertions on this function.
         * For example: with which arguments was it called?
         * Or how often is it called?
         */
        writeFileSync();
    });
}
```

And in the test

```
//file.test.js
const { writeFileSync } = require('fs')
jest.mock('fs');

describe('copies files based on user input', () => {
    test('calls writeFileSync', () => {
        expect(writeFileSync).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The closest I got is:

```
// __mocks__/readline.js

module.exports = {
    createInterface: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
        {
            question: jest.fn().mockImplementation(
                (question, cb) => {
                    writeFileSync()
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

But with that I am testing the test, I noticed. Anyone know how I can test what's inside the `rl.question()` callback? I'll gladly give more info if necessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it: it needs to mock the implementation and call the callback argument (`cb` in this case):

```js
// __mocks__/readline.js
module.exports = {
    createInterface: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        question: jest.fn()
            .mockImplementationOnce((questionText, cb) => {cb('')}) // test empty arg
            .mockImplementationOnce((questionText, cb) => {cb('foo')})
            .mockImplementationOnce((questionText, cb) => {cb('bar')})   
        })
    })
};
```

That returns `''`, `foo`, `bar` as mocked user input values.

Answer (score 1):

this is called test spies and Sinon.Js has a punch of helpers, 
check [the docs for examples](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/#using-a-spy-to-wrap-an-existing-method)

here, we can spy on fs.writeFileSync before running this test, and then use the spy inside your test.

```
const spy = sinon.spy(writeFileSync);
```

then you can assert on the spy call with [spy properties](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/#properties) such as:

```
 spy.callCount
 spy.calledWith()
 spy.calledOn()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your proposal unfortunately is not suited for my setup with jest. I've a found a way to do it in Jest (see answer).